# Python extension - Debug adapter process has terminated unexpectedly

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

After installing the Python extension, I find myself not being able to debug. When I select any of the default launch configurations and press the green arrow to start debugging, it notifies me with the error message in the title. I am not using any external modules, I am simply trying to run a single line hello world program and this error still appears. I have tried reinstalling the extension, deleting the `.vscode` folder and checking the path of my Python interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, it was gone after I delete c:\users\username\ .code and reinstall vscode. hope that helps.

Lidong

Comment: Although I didn't find a folder at that path, I found a folder called `.vscode` in my `Users\<name>\` folder which contained all of the installed extensions. I deleted the Python extension folder and reinstalled it, it seemed to work after that.

Comment: that's the path I meant.   looks like stackoverflow hide <username> from the path.